# Java array substring

Tags: java, arrays, select, instantiation

How can I create/instantiate an array to be equal to the substring of another array, where the size of the substring is unknown:

```
int n; //some number derived somewhere else

String[] grp = elements[i] to elements[i+n];
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create and array with the same values as another just longer in length?

Comment: A good (non-obvious) question. Note that I have replaced the word "selection" with "substring" in the question, which is the terminology you are after (even though it isn't a String, it is still the correct terminology in computer science terms).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original,
                                  int from,
                                  int to)
```

> Copies the specified range of the
>   specified array into a new array. The
>   initial index of the range (`from`) must
>   lie between zero and `original.length`,
>   inclusive. The value at `original[from]`
>   is placed into the initial element of
>   the copy (unless `from ==
>   original.length` or `from == to`). Values
>   from subsequent elements in the
>   original array are placed into
>   subsequent elements in the copy. The
>   final index of the range (`to`), which
>   must be greater than or equal to from,
>   may be greater than `original.length`,
>   in which case null is placed in all
>   elements of the copy whose index is
>   greater than or equal to
>   `original.length - from`. The length of
>   the returned array will be `to - from`.
>
> The resulting array is of exactly the
>   same class as the original array.

In your case:

```
String[] grp = Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, i, i + n);
```

Comment: `Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, i, i + n)` would exclude `elements[i+n]`.  To include it, you should use `Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, i, i+n+1)`.  But maybe the OP intended to copy n elements in which case your answer is correct.

Answer (score 9):

You will use `Arrays.copyOfRange()`.

Here is an example:

```
String[] original = some array;
String[] grp = Arrays.copyOfRange(original, i, i + n);
```

The [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for the `Arrays` class has lots of information about the method:

Comment: ＋1.  You should add `+1` to include `elements[i+n]` in the range.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String[] grp = Arrays.copyOfRange(grp, i, i+n);
```

As the name implies `grp` will be a *copy* of the original array and not a view into it. You can't have views into the array, for that you'd need to use a [collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). Generally speaking collections are the more powerful and flexible, high-level alternative to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of the array, you would do

```
String [] grp = new String[n + 1];//inclusive
```

Then, all you have to do is copy the elements over:

```
for(int x = 0;x < n + 1;x++)
{
    grp[x] = elements[i + x];//I'm assuming you have "i" defined somewhere
}
```